# Facebook Like button: use a variable to specify "current webpage" vs. manually including page URL?

Tags: facebook, url, variables

In the Facebook "like button" the  and  code snippets both require that an individual page URL be specified. The like button code snippet should go into an include, so obviously I would like to use some kind of variable in the like button code snippet so that it can automatically detect the current page URL. The Twitter, LinkedIn and GooglePlus buttons all automatically detect.

Here's my code. It's working just fine, but you can see where the individual page URL is being specified. Is there a variable that can be used instead, so the code snippet can be placed into an include?

Thanks.

<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.[MYWEBSITE].com%2F[MYPAGENAME.shtml]&send=false&layout=standard&width=50&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font=tahoma&height=20" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:46px; height:20px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `XFBML`/`HTML5` version of Like Button and omitting `href`/`data-href` attribute, by not including it in the code you're instructing JS-SDK to use current page URL while rendering Like Button.

Comment: OK, thanks--that does work. The only drawback: In the XFBML/HTML5 code, the FB button always has two parts--the fb icon plus words about liking this page, and the additional words make it a lot wider. This is different from the count "balloon/bubble." With iframe, I can just get a small (50px wide) like button itself. 
.
Any way to have it pull the current page URL with the iframe tag? I tried taking the href attriute out of the iframe. The button appears on the page but it doesn't look like the actual "like" function is clicking through to the Facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with iframe.

My code is:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) .'&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=21&amp;appId=438288506277662" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Notice the important part:

```
href='. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) .'
```

Hope that helps!
- Jack